# Android Studio - Break on first executed line

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to debug an Android app but it crashes even before it hits the onCreate method in the main activity class. Is there a way to automatically set a breakpont in Android Studio on the first line that's ever executed even if it is a API class?

Comment: Try to debug application class, maybe the issue is there.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to `Run > View Breakpoints` and then select `Exception Breakpoints` and `Java Exception Breakpoints`

*I'm not sure if this will help in your specific case though. You can try posting some code so we can help with the problem more specifically :)*

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention that I try to debug Smali. Sadly this doens't work, the app just starts and closes again and throws a very weird stack trace without breaking. Setting the breakpoint manually at the line mentioned in  the stacktrace halts the program though. That's why I wanna break the program on the first possible line.

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: It's been a while but I hope you can still help me.
This is my stacktrace:

https://pastebin.com/zpBfdLMF